# Django Template: Comparing Dictionary Length in IF Statement

Tags: python, django

I am trying to compare the length of a dictionary inside a django template

For example, I would like to know the correct syntax to do the following:

```
    {% if error_messages %}
        <div class="error">
            {% if length(error_messages) > 1 %}
                Please fix the following errors:
                <div class="erroritem">
                    {% for key, value in error_messages.items %}
                        <br>{{ value }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

            {% else %}
                    {% for key, value in error_messages.items %}
                        {{ value }}
                    {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this, using the [length](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length) filter and the [ifequal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal-and-ifnotequal) tag:

```
{% if error_messages %}
    <div class="error">
        {% ifequal error_messages|length 1 %}
            error_messages[0]
        {% else %}
            Please fix the following errors:
            <div class="erroritem">
            {% for key, value in error_messages.items %}
                <br>{{ value }}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endifequal %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Anything else will have to go down the path of [custom tags and filters](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags).

Comment: == 1 isn't the same as > 1 though. Django's template system can be a real pain sometimes...

Comment: You would only enter the IF when error_messages is >= 1, so if you ifequal to 1 inside and display the opposite case of what he wanted, the effect is the same.

Comment: Quick question, how do I get the first item in a dictionary. {{ error_messages|first }} doesn't work.

Comment: Yikes. I'm not really sure, as dictionaries really have no ordering so there's no concept of "first". As ugly as it may be, you could do a {% for .. %} and know that it's only going to execute once because the length of the dictionary is one. Otherwise you'd have to make a custom filter.

Comment: you can also use forloop.counter while looping in a dataset to filter when should the loop stop. if you got a lot of data already to visualize.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use both the `if` tag and the  `length` filter

```
{% if page_detail.page_content|length > 2 %}
<strong><a class="see-more" href="#" data-prevent-default="">
Learn More</a></strong>{% endif %}
```

**NB**
Ensure no spaces between the dictionary/object and the `length` filter when used in the `if` tag so as not to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

use the smart_if template tag:

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/

its super cool :)

can do all the obvious stuff like:

{% if articles|length >= 5 %}...{% endif %}

{% if "ifnotequal tag" != "beautiful" %}...{% endif %}